# script to traverse through directories and subdirectories to list files

Tags: linux, bash, subdirectory

```
#!/bin/bash
#script to loop through directories to merge files

mydir=/data/
files="/data/*"

for f in $files
do
    if[ -d "$f" ]
    then
            for ff in $f/*
            do
                    echo "Processing $ff"
            done
    else
            echo "Processing $f"
    fi
done
```

I have the above code to go through directories and sub-directories and list all the files. I am getting the error: syntax error near unexpected token `then'

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if [ -d "$f" ]
  ^
```

There needs to be a space between `if` and `[`. If you don't have a space, bash thinks you're trying to execute a command named `if[`.

---

```
files="/data/*"
for f in $files
```

Also know that this won't work. To store a wildcard expansion in a variable like that you need to use an array. The syntax is a bit hairier...

```
files=(/data/*)
for f in "${files[@]}"
```

Or you could write the wildcard inline the way you do with the inner loop. That would work fine.

```
for f in "$mydir"/*
```

---

For what it's worth, you could use `find` to recurse through all files and sub-directories recursively.

```
find /data/ -type f -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do
    echo "Processing $file"
done
```

`-type f` matches files only. `-print0` combined with `-d $'\0'` is a way to be extra careful with file names containing characters like spaces, tabs, and even newlines. It is legal to have these characters in file names so I like to write my scripts in a way that can handle them.

Note that this will recurse deeper than just sub-directories. It'll go all the way down. If that's not what you want, add `-maxdepth 2`.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, you could probably replace this entire loop with something like

```
# find all files either in /data or /data/subdir
find  /data -type f -maxdepth 2 | while read file; do
  echo $file;
end
```

Comment: I am using the loop because I am just testing my code by listing the file names now. I really have to do some other processing like merging files by going into a subdirectory, then coming out, going back into another subdirectory, merge files again and so on. Thanks for the input!

Comment: No problem.  Just wanted to make sure you were aware!

Comment: I am creating files dynamically in my program. Is there a way to assign them dynamically? I want their names to match my directory name.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that does what you ask, you pass it a folder see the call at the bottom func_process_folder_set "/folder".

```
    # --- -------------------------------- --- #
    # FUNC:  Process a folder of files
    # --- -------------------------------- --- #
    func_process_folder_set(){

        FOLDER="${1}"

        while read -rd $'\0' file; do

            fileext=${file##*.}  # -- get the .ext of file
            case ${fileext,,}    # -- make ext lowercase for checking in case statement
            echo "FILE: $file"   # -- print the file  (always use " " to handle file spaces)

        done < <(find  ${FOLDER} -type f -maxdepth 20 -name '*.*' -print0)

    }

    # -- call the function above with this:
    func_process_folder_set "/some/folder"
```